Second monitor is detected as "Unknown monitor"
I have a laptop Asus N56V, with Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2), and SyncMaster BX2335 monitor which is plugged in VGA port. There's Nvidia graphics in this laptop, but it has it's own problems and i'm not planning to use it. OS is Ubuntu 24.04.4 LTS.
When i connect the monitor, it detected as "unknown monitor" and i can not set resolution higher than 1024x768.
In windows on the same machine it works perfectly.
Tried:

delete ~/.config/monitors.xls
apt full-upgrade
ubuntu-drivers autoinstall (ended up with some error with Nvidia)
apt-get install mesa-utils (ended up with some error with Nvidia)
plugged it in before and after reboot
checked if in /etc/default/grub setting GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT is set to "quiet splash".

Some info:
$ lspci | grep VGA             
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 2944 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 350mm x 190mm
   1920x1080     59.88*+
   1440x1080     59.87  
   1400x1050     59.86  
   1280x1024     59.76  
   1280x960      59.79  
   1152x864      59.78  
   1024x768      59.68  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.85  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.20  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.82  
   1368x768      59.71  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.45  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
XWAYLAND1 connected 1024x768+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      59.92*+
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77

What can i do about it?
Edit:
Now i'm trying to manually add needed resolution, but get a strange error:
$ cvt 1920 1080 60
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

$ xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND1 "1920x1080_60.00"

$ xrandr --output XWAYLAND1 --mode "1920x1080_60.00"
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
  Value in failed request:  0x780
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  29

Also tried with no dots in the name of mode, got the same error.
